# Adding persistent updates to channels in Twilio Programmable Chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

We have recently implemented group chat functionality for an existing application using Twilio Programmable Chat.

Context: The application allows users to connect with each other and join groups. We are using Twilio to add a real-time chat room within each group so that group members can communicate. So when a user joins a group, he/she accesses the Twilio chat channel, as well as various other group resources.

When a user joins a group (as defined by our app), it seems that they are not considered a member of the group's channel unless they are active in the chatroom (i.e., when app is not in foreground, user is not listed as channel member). We are trying to do find some way to introduce persistent notifications for the group in the Twilio channel (i.e., "John Smith has joined the group" or "Jane Smith has left the group"). In another SO discussion, [philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash) had mentioned using the Twilio REST API to send system-authored messages with this information, and then manage these messages on the UI side to format them as group "updates". That makes sense!

My questions are:

1. Do I need to handle sending system-authored messages on our backend? If so, I'll need to add a field to my Groups model to include the Twilio channel SID for the group.
2. Is it possible to mute notifications for these system-authored messages (which will be formatted as "channel updates")? I.e., is it possible to not send push notifications to users whenever the message being sent is authored by system?

I hope my questions are clear enough. Thanks so much for any answers or guidance anyone can provide for the above!!

Comment: That was my answer! I hadn't considered notifications though. I'm going to check with the team and follow up as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm told that it's not currently possible to send a message and not trigger a notification. I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to register that you are interested in this feature as that will help it get prioritised.